# select query with 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have page where people can post comments and page where people can click "follow" on other people profiles (same as LIKE on Facebook)

I would like to have SELECT query that will post all the comments I have, but will order them with the follow way:
first, print the 2 newest comments (they must been posted this week) of the lastest people you click FOLLOW.
second, post the rest of the posted, order them by create-date

(I'm using linux time)

Can you help me with the SQL query?

this is my current SELECT query. it pull all comment by create-date:

```
 SELECT id, userID, text, createDate FROM `comments` AS comment WHERE (comment.refID = 0) AND (comment.pageName = 'yard') AND 1=1 ORDER BY comment.createDate DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

"followers" table looks like this:

```
userID  ownerID     createDate
1       2           1439019657
1       4           1438940399
```

"comments" table looks loke this:

```
 id     userID  pageName    refID   text    createDate
220      1       yard       0       text1    1438030967
227      1       yard       0       text2    1438031704
228      1       yard       0       text3    1438031704
```

Comment: And desired result looks like this

Answer (score 0):

I might've messed up followers' relations. Example data looks incoplete for full context. It shows userID=1 comments for sure, but either no one who follows userID=1 or both 3 and 4 follow him. No idea what refID is doing in comments table. Query shows only a concept anyway - you'll figure out details.

```
SELECT un.* FROM ((
    SELECT 1 as priority, comment.id, comment.userID, comment.text, comment.createDate
    FROM `comments` as comment
    INNER JOIN `followers` as follower ON follower.userID = comment.userID
    WHERE comment.refID = 0
      AND comment.pageName = 'yard'
      AND ...
    ORDER BY follower.createDate DESC LIMIT 2
) UNION DISTINCT (
    SELECT 2 as priority, id, userID, text, createDate
    FROM `comments` as comment
    WHERE comment.refID = 0
      AND comment.pageName = 'yard'
)) as un ORDER BY un.priority, un.createDate DESC LIMIT 20
```